# OSMnx Error: No module named 'pyproj.compat'

Tags: python, anaconda, geopandas, osmnx, pyproj

I am attempting to try out some applications of [OSMnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx). The installation goes through without errors following the provided [installation guide](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) using Anaconda3 in Windows 10. However, upon importing the package,

```
import osmnx as ox
```

I receive the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj.compat'
```

I have attempted various methods of installation:

- ['conda' install](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- ['pip' install using Gohlke wheels](https://gist.github.com/gboeing/a6fcb39a9010d142446f4a83e43d8d6c)

No matter the install method, I receive the same error. The error also appears when importing `pyproj` alone.

I am stuck. Any suggestions for finding and solving my issue?

Conda environment info (from strict channel priority):

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.12                     py_0    conda-forge
altair                    3.2.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
asn1crypto                0.24.0                py37_1003    conda-forge
astroid                   2.2.5                    py37_0    conda-forge
attrs                     19.1.0                     py_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
bleach                    3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.70.0               h6a4c333_2    conda-forge
branca                    0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.6.16            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.12.3           py37hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
cfitsio                   3.470                hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003    conda-forge
click                     7.0                        py_0    conda-forge
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               1.2.1                      py_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cryptography              2.7              py37hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.65.3               h4496350_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_1    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.5.0                      py_1    conda-forge
descartes                 1.1.0                      py_3    conda-forge
docutils                  0.15.2                   py37_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3                   py37_1000    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.5             habb2df7_1003    conda-forge
fiona                     1.8.6            py37h2979200_4    conda-forge
folium                    0.10.0                     py_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.0               h563cfd7_1    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.5             hd288d7e_1002    conda-forge
gdal                      2.4.2            py37he6b6c38_4    conda-forge
geographiclib             1.49                       py_0    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
geopy                     1.20.0                     py_0    conda-forge
geos                      3.7.2                habb2df7_1    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.5.1                h8f84788_2    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          hb01d8f6_1002    conda-forge
glib                      2.58.3            hc0c2ac7_1002    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13            hf8e6fe8_1002    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.5          nompi_hcc15c50_1100    conda-forge
icu                       64.2                 he025d50_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.8                   py37_1000    conda-forge
imagesize                 1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
ipykernel                 5.1.2            py37h5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.7.0            py37h5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.15.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.10.1                     py_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9c                hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.0.2                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
kealib                    1.4.10            hf7dc31f_1005    conda-forge
keyring                   19.0.2                   py37_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37he980bc4_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.16.3            hdd46e55_1001    conda-forge
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0                    12_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0                    12_mkl    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.65.3               h4496350_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1             h6538335_1006    conda-forge
libgdal                   2.4.2                h2bdb96c_4    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.15              hfa6e2cd_1005    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             h4ece8bf_1010    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0                    12_mkl    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.6.2             ha953453_1002    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h7602738_0    conda-forge
libpq                     11.5                 hb0bdaea_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.17               h2fa13f4_0    conda-forge
libspatialindex           1.8.5                he025d50_4    conda-forge
libspatialite             4.3.0a            h832c139_1029    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.8.2                h642c060_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.10            h6512ee2_1003    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.9                h9ce36c8_2    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.8.3             he025d50_1001    conda-forge
m2w64-expat               2.1.1                         2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gettext             0.19.7                        2
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libiconv            1.14                          6
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
m2w64-xz                  5.2.2                         2
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.1.1                    py37_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.1.1            py37h2852a4a_1    conda-forge
mccabe                    0.6.1                      py_1    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.4                      245
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
munch                     2.3.2                      py_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 5.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
networkx                  2.3                        py_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.17.0           py37hc71023c_0    conda-forge
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.3.1                ha922770_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1c               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
osmnx                     0.10                       py_1    conda-forge
packaging                 19.0                       py_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.25.0           py37he350917_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.7.3                         0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.41              h6538335_1003    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pip                       19.2.2                   py37_0    conda-forge
poppler                   0.67.0               h92819f6_7    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.9                         1    conda-forge
postgresql                11.5                 h06f7779_0    conda-forge
proj4                     6.1.0                hc2d0af5_2    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                      py_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.6.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pycodestyle               2.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_1    conda-forge
pyflakes                  2.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pylint                    2.3.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pyproj                    2.2.1            py37h3f740ce_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.15.4           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
python                    3.7.3                h510b542_1    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2019.2                     py_0    conda-forge
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pyzmq                     18.0.2           py37h16f9016_2    conda-forge
qt                        5.9.7                h506e8af_3    conda-forge
qtawesome                 0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
qtconsole                 4.5.2                      py_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_1    conda-forge
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0    conda-forge
rtree                     0.8.3           py37h21ff451_1002    conda-forge
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
shapely                   1.6.4           py37ha35856d_1006    conda-forge
sip                       4.19.8          py37h6538335_1000    conda-forge
six                       1.12.0                py37_1000    conda-forge
snowballstemmer           1.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinx                    2.1.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_0    conda-forge
spyder-kernels            0.5.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.29.0               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.2                   py_1001    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.9             hfa6e2cd_1002    conda-forge
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.0.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2                 py37_1000    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.25.3                   py37_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vincent                   0.4.4                      py_1    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_4
wcwidth                   0.1.7                      py_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                   py37_1002    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.2             h6538335_1004    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4             h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.2                h6538335_2    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h2fa13f4_1005    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.0                hd8a0e53_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: Which version of `pyproj` do you have? Is it from conda-forge?

Comment: One attempt used pyproj 2.2.2 from pypi, another used 1.9.6 from Gohlke wheels and yet another install attempt used pyproj 2.2.1 from conda-forge. All were installed without error, but no success in importing any of them in Spyder. @martinfleis

Comment: I would recommend raising an issue on the Spyder repo. It seems like it works when not using Spyder.

Comment: @snowman2 Actually, it doesn't work at the command line either. I'm just normally working in Spyder. That's why I framed my statement around Spyder. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you provide your conda environment information? `conda list`? Also, are you using the strict channel priority to install?

Comment: @snowman2 Just updated the post with my conda environment information.